# How can I get both the rows that fit into a date range, and the single most recent row prior to the given date range per ID?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to provide a query a date range, for example 11/01/2021 - 11/30/2021. From there I want to get all relevant rows that fall within that date range, which is pretty straightforward - just a simple select with a where clause based on the to and from dates. But after this, I want to get the most recent row (if it exists) prior to the date range, *only* for the foreign key IDs that appear within the date range.

So as an example,

| ID | FK ID | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 | 09/05/2021 |
| 2 | 101 | 10/29/2021 |
| 3 | 101 | 11/05/2021 |
| 4 | 201 | 11/20/2021 |
| 5 | 301 | 08/13/2021 |
| 6 | 401 | 11/01/2021 |
| 7 | 401 | 11/23/2021 |

If I were to input a date range of 11/01/2021 - 11/30/2021, I would expect the following results

| ID | FK ID | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 101 | 10/29/2021 |
| 3 | 101 | 11/05/2021 |
| 4 | 201 | 11/20/2021 |
| 6 | 401 | 11/01/2021 |
| 7 | 401 | 11/23/2021 |

My first thought was a UNION, where the second query grabs the max date prior to the date range and unions with the first query which has all the values in the given date range. But I think this would fail with values like ID 5 in the table above - because there's no restriction on the second query that it would need the same FK ID to exist in the first table. Maybe I'm just not thinking straight but I can't think of any way to restrict a union in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a cte to select rows within the range and add more rows relative to this cte

```
with cte as (
  SELECT *
  FROM tb
  WHERE [Date] >= '11/1/2021' AND [Date] <= '11/30/2021'
)
select * 
from cte
union all
select *
from (
  select top(1) with ties *
  from tb
  where exists (select 1 from cte where cte.fk_id = tb.fk_id)
     and [Date] < '11/1/2021'
  order by row_number() over(partition by fk_id order by [date] desc)
) t
order by id;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=131420e8f338dbd30611754709df6edd)

Comment: This solution nearly works, however for some reason, using `top(1)` was only returning the single row with the highest date regardless of fk_id. I got it working by removing `top(1) with ties` and adding this condition after the exists condition `and [Date] = (select max([Date]) from tb tb2 where tb2.FK_ID = tb.FK_ID and [Date] < '11/1/2021')`. I don't really like that I had to use a subquery though so still open to improvements.

Comment: @ryan.kom,  `partition by fk_id` was missing, my bad. See the edited version.

Answer (score 0):

The following query produces the output you want

```
WITH cte AS(
  SELECT ID,FK_ID,[DATE]
  FROM tb
  WHERE [DATe] >= '11/1/2021' AND [Date] <= '11/30/2021')
SELECT * 
FROM cte    
UNION ALL  
SELECT ID,FK_ID,[DATE]
FROM
    (SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN LEAD([Date]) over(ORDER BY ID) >= '11/1/2021' AND LEAD([Date]) over(ORDER BY ID) <= '11/30/2021' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS rnk
     FROM tb) t
  WHERE rnk = 1 AND [DATe] < '11/1/2021' AND FK_ID IN (SELECT FK_ID FROM cte)
ORDER BY ID
```

demo in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0bc12bb5b8f5418949305a2f821ec4b9)

Comment: This is very close, but the reason ID 5 needs to be excluded is because FK ID `301` does not exist within the date range. So basically, the condition is that I only get the most recent row prior to the date range, if at least one row exists within the date range

Comment: That is, give the last dates whose FK_ID are in the list of accepted dates. I edited the answer.